# How to make the answer appear automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I made a master mind game and im stuck with the last part of it. The Question is.. How can i make the 4 small buttons on the right side to Show the answer automatically after pressing on "2nd row button" (btnRow2)? Right now, my code is working perfectly except the fact that i have to press on the answer Buttons in order to check if the Colors choosen by me are correct or not, i want them to appear automatically without pressing on the buttons.

[image]

**My 2nd Row Button code**

}

```
private void btnRow2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnChange1_1.Enabled = false;
    btnChange1_2.Enabled = false;
    btnChange1_3.Enabled = false;
    btnChange1_4.Enabled = false;

    btnChange2_1.Enabled = true;
    btnChange2_2.Enabled = true;
    btnChange2_3.Enabled = true;
    btnChange2_4.Enabled = true;
    btnRow2.Visible = false;

    pictureBox2.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Visible = false;

    btnAnswer1_1.Visible = true;
    btnAnswer1_2.Visible = true;
    btnAnswer1_3.Visible = true;
    btnAnswer1_4.Visible = true;



}
```

**All small Answer boxes:**

```
 }

        private void btnAnswer1_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnChange1_1.BackColor == button1.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_1.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            if (btnChange1_1.BackColor == button2.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_1.BackColor == button3.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_1.BackColor == button4.BackColor)
            {

            }

            {
                btnChange1_4.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_3.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_2.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_1.Enabled = false;

            }



        }

        private void btnAnswer1_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnChange1_2.BackColor == button1.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_2.BackColor == button2.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_2.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            if (btnChange1_2.BackColor == button3.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_2.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_2.BackColor == button4.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_2.BackColor = Color.Red;

                {
                    btnChange1_4.Enabled = false;
                    btnChange1_3.Enabled = false;
                    btnChange1_2.Enabled = false;
                    btnChange1_1.Enabled = false;



                }

            }
        }



        private void btnAnswer1_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (btnChange1_3.BackColor == button1.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_3.BackColor == button2.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_3.BackColor == button3.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_3.BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            if (btnChange1_3.BackColor == button4.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_3.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            {
                btnChange1_4.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_3.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_2.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_1.Enabled = false;





            }
        }

        private void btnAnswer1_4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (btnChange1_4.BackColor == button1.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_4.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_4.BackColor == button2.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_4.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_4.BackColor == button3.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_4.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            if (btnChange1_4.BackColor == button4.BackColor)
            {
                btnAnswer1_4.BackColor = Color.Black;

            }

            {
                btnChange1_4.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_3.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_2.Enabled = false;
                btnChange1_1.Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method that does what your answer buttons do, and call that method when you press row 2.

That is my suggestions anyway, but I am a bit confused to what you actually want :) GL

Comment: i want those 4 Little Buttons to Show  black or red Color (as you can see it in the code) I want the Colors to appear if the answer is correct without pressing on any of the 4 Little Buttons (btnAnswer)   In simple words. Right now when i want to see whether my Colors in the bigger Buttons are correct, i Need to press the 4 Little Buttons (btnAnswer). I want it to Show automatically without clicking on it...

Comment: Then I think my suggestion still works. Make a method for each or a dynamic method, which is called when you take a guess. If the guess is correct, then it changes.

- Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: How to do that? Sorry, Im new in the bussiness